# Custom plots using the effects package

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression

I try to customize the multiline graphs from the effects package.

Is there anyway to position the legend in the example below within the plotting area and not above the graph?

Alternatively: Does anyone know how to plot the results of the multiline regressions calculated by the effects package using ggplot2?

I appreciate any help.

Andy

**Example:**

```
library(effects)
data(Prestige)
mod5 <- lm(prestige ~ income*type + education, data=Prestige)
eff_cf <- effect("income*type", mod5)
print(plot(eff_cf, multiline=TRUE))
```

Comment: Can you show sample data like what you did in effects package.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I updated my question with an example

Answer (score 3):

This is how you plot effect object in ggplot

```
library(ggplot2)

## Change effect object to dataframe
eff_df <- data.frame(eff_cf)

## Plot ggplot with legend on the bottom
ggplot(eff_df)+geom_line(aes(income,fit,linetype=type))+theme_bw()+
  xlab("Income")+ylab("Prestige")+coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,25000),ylim=c(30,110))+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

You can change `xlim` and `ylim` depending on how you want to display your data.

The output is as follows:
[image]

Comment: just one additional question here - how would you most elegantly add the 95% confidence limits or 95% prediction bands here, say showing the 3 groups in three different colours (using solid & dotted lines) and maybe also the actual data points in different colours? There is no option in the effects package right to also show the actual data points?

Answer (score 3):

From `?xyplot` you read :

> Alternatively, the key can be positioned inside the plot region by
>   specifying components `x`, `y` and corner. `x` and `y` determine the location
>   of the corner of the key given by corner, which is usually one of
>   `c(0,0)`, `c(1,0)`, `c(1,1)` and `c(0,1)`, which denote the corners of the
>   unit square.

and from `?plot.eff` you read

> key.args   additional arguments to be passed to the key trellis
>   argument to xyplot or densityplot, e.g., to position the key (legend)
>   in the plotting region.

So for example you can do the following:

```
plot(eff_cf, multiline=TRUE,    
     key.args=list(x=0.2,y=0.9,corner=c(x=1, y=1)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Based on Ruben's answer, you can try following:

```
library(sjPlot)
sjp.int(mod5, type = "eff", swapPredictors = T)
```

which will reproduce the plot with `ggplot`, and `sjp.int` also returns the plot object for further customization. However, you can also set certain legend-parameters with the sjPlot-package:

```
sjp.setTheme(legend.pos = "bottom right", 
             legend.inside = T)
sjp.int(mod5, type = "eff", swapPredictors = T)
```

which gives you following plot:

[image]

See [sjPlot-manual](http://www.strengejacke.de/sjPlot/custplot/) for examples on how to customize plot-appearance and legend-position/size etc.

For plotting estimates of your model as forest plot, or marginal effects of all model terms, see `?sjp.lm` in the sjPlot-package, or you may even try out the latest features in my package [from GitHub](https://github.com/sjPlot/devel).

Answer (score 1):

@Tom Wenseleers

You can use `sjPlot::sjp.int` with `type='eff'` for this.

However, it won't give you rug plots and no raw data points yet either.

```
mod5 <- lm(prestige ~ type * income + education, data=Prestige)
library(sjPlot)
sjp.int(mod5,showCI = T, type = 'eff')
```

There's an argument `partial.residuals = T` to the `effect()` function.
This gives you fitted values, partial.residuals.raw and partial.residuals.adjusted.
I suppose you could merge that data on the original dataset and then plot smooths by group, but I ran into some difficulties early on (e.g. `na.action=na.exclude` is not respected).