# Plotting SPSS style moderation (interaction) example

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to plot something like the SPSS style moderation graph [here (bottom image)](http://my.ilstu.edu/~jhkahn/medmod.html) in R. I tried using the `QuantPsyc` package but failed utterly. Can someone help me plot this correctly? I am not expecting the exact data in the image, that is just the formatting I want. I am using `data(tra)` for this example. I tried:

```
data(tra)
lm.mod1 <- moderate.lm(beliefs, values, attitudes, tra)
ss.mod1 <- sim.slopes(lm.mod1, tra$values)
## requires user interaction 
graph.mod(ss.mod1,beliefs,attitudes,tra,"Interaction Example")
```

which was not at all what I was looking for. Thanks to the comments I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17658933/custom-plots-using-the-effects-package), which led me to this code:

```
library(effects)
data(Prestige)
mod5 <- lm(prestige ~ income*type + education, data=Prestige)
eff_cf <- effect("income*type", mod5)
print(plot(eff_cf, multiline=TRUE))
```

which is closer, but still doesnt have the right format, specifically:

- the data plotted is not restricted to one standard deviation above and below the mean (as I believe it is in the example)
- the x axis is labeled (where it is not in SPSS)

Comment: Are you looking for something to the effect of the [`effects` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/effects/index.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this relatively easily manually by predicting values. I'm guessing there's some sort of typo in your post because "type" is a categorical predictor in the Prestige dataset. I'll assume you want "income * education" instead. For plotting, I've used the `ggplot2` package just because I'm more familiar with it than with base graphics, but there's probably a solution there too. I've gone way overboard with the plotting detail here but it seems like you really want to exactly mimic the example you linked so that's what I did.

```
# model
mod5 <- lm(prestige ~ income * education, data = Prestige)

# first, create data frame to store predictions
m <- mean(Prestige$education) # mean of education
s <- sd(Prestige$education) # sd of education
newdata <- data.frame(education = c(rep(m - s, 2), rep(m, 2), rep(m + s, 2)), # add in +/- 1 SD and mean
    income = with(Prestige, rep(range(income), 3))) # range of income values

# predict new values using the predict() function
newdata$prestige.predicted <- predict(mod5, newdata)

# plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(newdata, aes(x = income, y = prestige.predicted, linetype = factor(education))) +
    geom_line() +
    scale_linetype_manual(values = c("dotted", "solid", "dashed"), name = "Education", labels = c("1 SD Below Mean", "Mean", "1 SD Above Mean")) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), # get rid of axis labels
          axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(), # get rid of vertical lines
          panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "black"), # make horizontal gridlines black
          panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank())
```

[Resulting graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0vj2.jpg)